# A calculation question about Taylor expansion in Altland and Simons p 106, the gutter like potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, condensed-matter, differentiation, approximations

I have a question regarding the book condensed matter field theory by Altland Simons p 106. In their a gutter like potential is given and it is required to calculate the fluctuation $\delta V_{tension}$ because of transverse fluctuation $\delta x$ by an amount $\delta u$.
And it goes like this:
$ \delta V_{tension}= \sigma [(du^2+dx^2)^{1/2}-dx]  \approx \sigma dx (\frac{\partial u}{\partial x})^2/2$

I don't know how to get the result from the left to the right side, someone told me to use Taylor expansion, but I still don't get it.

[image]

Comment: $\sqrt{\Delta u^2 + \Delta x^2}= \sqrt{\Delta x^2 (1+ \tfrac{\Delta u^2}{\Delta x^2})}  =\Delta x \sqrt{1+\tfrac{\Delta u^2}{\Delta x^2} } \approx  \Delta x (1+\tfrac{1}{2} (\tfrac{\Delta u}{\Delta x})^2)$, where in the last step we made use of the Taylor approximation of $\sqrt{1+y^2}$ with $y=\Delta u/\Delta x$. Of course all of this is a bit hand-waving, e.g. we have to discuss the sign of $\Delta x$ and take care with the limit $\Delta x \to 0$.

Comment: Ok I get it!!thanks!!

Comment: Fine. But you should really think about e.g. the sign of $\Delta x$; here I assumed it is non-negative, else an absolute value must appear, which might cause some trouble when you want to convert a finite difference to a derivative (?). That's why I only commented instead of writing an answer...There might be a physical reason to assume that it is non-negative, tho.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I think all you used was $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$. The reason we are taking the positive root is because distances are positive.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your comment. Indeed. But I don't know if $\Delta x$ represents a distance at all and not some generic change in *some* variable, which can be negative. Rather, in the end, $\Delta x \to \mathrm dx$... Additionally, when transforming the finite difference to the derivative, we also in principle should allow negative $\Delta x$. Again: There might be a physical reason to only consider non-negative $\Delta x$, but I haven't checked the actual, physical, problem at all, tbh. And I don't know how the authors proceed.